# Renderable is mirrored

Tags: android, arcore

I'm rendering a view at an anchor using `node.loadView(this@MainActivity, R.layout.marker)`.  This works, but the view marker is appearing mirrored the left is on the right and vice versa.  Attempting to put a 180 degree rotation on the node didn't help.  Any other way to flip it back?

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a solution.  I set a scale on the node of Scale(-1.0f, 1f, 1f) and it flips the x direction